# "Derivation" of group velocity and "sharply" peaked wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dispersion

I was reading BH Bransden's chapter on wave packets and he derives the group velocity expression taking into account that: $$ \psi (x,t)=\int e^{i[p_{x}x-E(p_{x})t]/ \hbar} \phi (p_{x}) dp_{x} $$
where $\phi (p_{x}) $ is very "sharply peaked" at $p_{x}=p_{0} $.
It is clear that if we make this "sharply peaked" assumption we can derive a group velocity by saying that $|\psi (x,t)| $ is largest around $p_{0}$ if and only if the phase inside the wave function doesn't oscillate, because if it did oscillate a lot then the value of the integral would be small, and as we want to see when $|\psi (x,t)| $ is the largest we just need to set the derivative of this phase to zero. If we do that we see that $v_{g}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial k}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_{x}}$

My question is:
Why do we need the wave function to be sharply peaked around a certain value of the momentum? The only thing that comes to my mind is that we want to know the group velocity of a wave function whose momentum we know (or we have measured) without uncertainty, which means that the wave function needs to collapse and therefore the wave function needs to me a dirac delta.
I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

The point is of course, to talk about the group velocity of a free particle with a somewhat well defined momentum. If you use a Dirac delta function then you throw any concept of "group" or particle localization away, e.g. the uncertainty in the particle's position is infinite. Thus, if one uses a sharply peaked function for the momentum space wave function, such as a Gaussian, then the position space wave function will also be a Gaussian, albeit a somewhat wider Gaussian, i.e. there is still some concept of a wave packet or "free particle" moving through space with a group velocity and well defined momentum.